# Rails asset pipleline: compile to multiple stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Due to a specific setup, I would like to split the compiled stylesheets in two files. This is because (a part of) the CSS is needed for a Java application which can parse the CSS, but it is a bit buggy and can't handle some css-(hack)-syntax. Because I am unable to modify this Java application, I want to feed it only the CSS which it needs and of which I can make sure it is correct.

So, normally the assets pipeline would produce just one '/assets/application-[..].css' file. It would to let it also generate '/assets/custom-[..].css', based on a file selection I make. This still can be pre-compiled.

Is there a way to do this? Although I understand this is not the ideal setup..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To tell rails about additional files you wish to have precompiled, you can add them to the `config.assets.precompile` setting.

```
config.assets.precompile += ["other_application.css"]
```

You only see `application.css` in your HTML because that's the only file you're including

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

If you have some `custom.css.scss` in your `apps/assets/stylesheets` directory, it will be compiled just like `application.css`.

For example, I might have

```
- _common.css.scss
- application.css.erb.scss
- other_application.css.erb.scss
```

in `app/assets/stylesheets`. In the top of the non-partial files I will put

```
@import "common";
```

to include `_common.css.scss`. I can now reference either stylesheet independent of one another in a layout.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
# or
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "other_application" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but unfortunately I can't get it to work. When I include a _common.css.scss file in /app/assets/stylesheets, it does not appear as a compiled file (I use Heroku and the Heroku console to browse the files). Also, only application.css gets treated as a manifest file. other_application.css does not get compiled, even if I refer to it using stylesheet_link_tag.
--update--
To make other_application.css available I needed it to add to config.assets.precompile += %w( other_application.css ) in production.rb

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer. I double checked my application code and realized I had `config.assets.precompile` set with a glob that grabs all files from `app/assets/stylesheets` not prefixed with `_`. Sorry for the confusion; what I had stated in my answer originally is true for my applications alone :)

Comment: Also worth pointing out, this same setting is used for your JS files, to get additional files like `application.js` to precompile