# rails 4 asset pipeline assets.rb refactor issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

> Asset filtered out and will not be served: add
>   `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css )` to
>   `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

I am trying to setup multiple layouts that hit different .css.scss and .js setups, one for the home page, and others for various sections of the application.

My home layout looks like:

```
doctype html
= render 'layouts/components/view_source_msg'
html
  head
    title
      = browser_title(yield(:title))
    = render 'layouts/components/meta'
    = render 'layouts/components/favicons'
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'home'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  body[class="#{build_body_class} loading"]

    == yield
    = render 'layouts/components/analytics'
    = javascript_include_tag 'home'

    javascript:
      $(function(){
        $(document).foundation();
        view_#{controller.controller_name.downcase}.init();
      });
```

The error states to setup an initializer assets.rb which I have setup as:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css.sass )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css.scss )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js.coffee )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js.coffee.erb )
```

But this is not working...  Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you

**Update**

I was able to get this working by...

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css )
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.js )
```

But this seems a bit off. In my old rails applications the other methods would have worked just fine...

Comment: I'm confused by your syntax here. I did just take a working application, added a new test.css file, and referenced it from a layout using the `stylesheet_link_tag` method, and rails used it no problem without the fix you did (I just had it change all text to red to indicate it worked). This is a stupid question, but you did put a `home.css` file in your `app/assets/stylesheets` folder, right?

Comment: @RobW. yes, I did, but it is actually at home.css.scss file.  Not that the sass extension should matter, but I am more concerned with why the wild cards would not work. I know I am missing something small here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Rails v4, the sprockets gem now handles the asset pipeline. It looks for stylesheet files inside the `app/assets/stylesheets` and the `vendor/assets/stylesheets` folders, so if you are putting `home.css` in `public/assets/stylesheets` or something, it's not going to look there. If you specifically tell rails to precompile any asset matching that name, like you did in your fix, it will do so and then output the compiled stylesheet and know to reference it, so that's why it works. However this is not the preferred convention. [Ruby API for Coding Links to Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)

Comment: And ensure that your `application.css` file has these lines:
`    *= require_self`
`    *= require_tree .`

Comment: The file is located in the app/assets/stylesheets directory and I made sure the *= require_self and I still have to use Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( home.css ) in the initializer.  Is *= require_tree needed if you are only requiring the top level file?

Comment: Hmm, this is really leaving me scratching my head. What version of Rails? 

And yes, even top level files need that as the sprockets pipeline looks at application.css and application.js to determine which assets it needs to require. [Ruby API on manifest files and directives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)

Comment: this is rails 4.1, and I finding i.e. rails does not look for the file be default. http://jaketrent.com/post/rename-files-in-asset-pipeline/  so if you want to use = stylesheet_link_tag 'home' for the home layout and = stylesheet_link_tag 'application' for the others you have to add it to the assets.rb initializer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435520/rails-asset-pipleline-compile-to-multiple-stylesheets

Comment: Interesting... I guess since you never reference application.css in that layout, it doesn't bother precompiling it, and therefore never ends up compiling home.css, either. Well, anyway, guess you answered your own question!