# Split css and javascript files while in rails development

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, config

While in development mode, all my css and javascript files are combined into one, while in my browser inspector, I can only see the one css file Why is this happening? Thanks!

This is my layout code for those lines:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true, defer: defer ? :defer : false
```

Comment: Please  can you give some details to your environment set up? Which development tools are you using?

Comment: I am just using Google chrome inspector, which shows the specific files a css style is located in, it always shows this:
/assets/application-2186a546c7136adb1a5bba56a99368d179e1e560f9eacf37a2c0f2d1a93a2a1b.css @BenCummins

Comment: Yes, but what did you build the code in? Some IDE's have options to combine all CSS / js files into one to speed up the loading in the web browser

Comment: Even in the HTML it only shows this

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-2186a546c7136adb1a5bba56a99368d179e1e560f9eacf37a2c0f2d1a93a2a1b.css" data-turbolinks-track="true">

Comment: @BenCummins I am just using sublime text 3, with no IDE plugins or anything like that, Viewing the file in vim shows what I pasted in the question above.

Comment: I've not used rails myself, but it looks like in stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag you have caching options, make sure its not enabled in there.  Also in your environment configuration, make sure you have config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false

Comment: you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435520/rails-asset-pipleline-compile-to-multiple-stylesheets or section 3 in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by changing this line to true in

```
config/environments/development.rb

config.assets.debug = true

# Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
# This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
# number of complex assets.
```

Comment: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/162 - there's a bug on this, particularly application.css